# Implement bootstrap gapless card-columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

the current bootstrap implementation of card-columns has gaps.
any idea what the css would be to achieve no gaps?

i have tried something like

```
.card {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

but this doesn't affect anything.

any idea would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Is the gap on the card or on the column which contains the card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the `card` class. You are looking for it wrapper, which has the property `column-gap: 1.25rem;`. If you set the style `.card-columns { column-gap: 0; }`, you would remove the space between the columns.

Add `.card-columns .card { margin-bottom: 0; }` to completely remove the spaces.